# boost bimap invalid iterator

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use a member of a class of the below type:

```
boost::bimaps::bimap<std::filesystem::path, int> mRowIndexes = {};
```

When using the following code

```
PB::printDebug("mRowIndexes %d\n", mRowIndexes.size());
if (mRowIndexes.empty())
{
  PB::printDebug("Bimap empty\n");
}
if (mRowIndexes.left.begin() != mRowIndexes.left.end())
{
  PB::printDebug("F1\n");
}
if (mRowIndexes.begin() != mRowIndexes.end())
{
  PB::printDebug("F2\n");
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[Debug] mRowIndexes 0
[Debug] Bimap empty
[Debug] F1
[Debug] F2
```

Any idea what is wrong with the iterator? Why is the iterator different than the .end()?
Thank you!

Comment: Please post a [mre] so that we can compile it and get the same output as you get. Please also tell us what output you actually expect to get.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're doing something else wrong. This is not reproducible from the code shown:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e826dba1a428ca88)**

```cpp
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
namespace bm = boost::bimaps;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

namespace PB {
    inline void printDebug(char const* msg) { std::printf("%s", msg); }
    inline void printDebug(char const* fmt, auto const&... args) { std::printf(fmt, args...); }
} // namespace PB

void probe(auto const& m) {
    PB::printDebug("mRowIndexes %d\n", m.size());
    bool empty = m.empty();
    bool F1    = m.left.begin() != m.left.end();
    bool F2    = m.begin() != m.end();
    PB::printDebug("Bimap: size %d, %s%s%s\n",    //
                   m.size(),                      //
                   empty ? "empty" : "not empty", //
                   F1 ? ", F1" : "",              //
                   F2 ? ", F2" : "");
}

int main() {
    bm::bimap<fs::path, int> mRowIndexes = {};

    probe(mRowIndexes);

    for (int i = 0; auto& e : fs::directory_iterator(".", fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
        mRowIndexes.insert({e.path(), i++});

    probe(mRowIndexes);
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
mRowIndexes 0
Bimap: size 0, empty
mRowIndexes 2
Bimap: size 2, not empty, F1, F2
```

Without seeing your other code we cannot help, but look-out for [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), e.g. using `-fsanitize=address,undefined` or tools like `valgrind`